# Which drop down from the multiple drop down on a page is selected?

Tags: jquery, forms, select, submit

I have 3 drop down (combo boxes) or select lists on a page. It currently gives me the value from the first drop down box.
I am looking for a way to know

1. Which drop down's value is selected and has submitted value?
2. Disable the other two drop down's so that only 1 value is selected?

I am using jquery to check the value using this

```
var id = $("select option:selected").attr("value");
```

Any suggestions in jQuery to achieve 1 and 2 above?

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/rd2K4/1/
Thanks.

Comment: You have three combo boxes, each of which has a null option, representing user not having made a choice from that list.  Is that right?  You care about which select has a non-void option selected? Is that correct? [edit: removed misinfo about :selected]

Comment: Hmm, the solution below does most of what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the following should work.  It handles the change event for all select elements.  When one is changed, it disables the others and stores the selected value into a `selectedValue` variable:

```
$(function() {
    var selects = $("select");
    selects.on("change", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var selectedValue = $this.val();
        selects.not($this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

        // do something with the selectedValue here ...
    });
});
```

Note: The use of `.on()` requires jQuery 1.7+

Demo link can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/QnKGu/

Comment: I updated your demo to include the JavaScript so that you can see a working solution.  You can find that here: http://jsfiddle.net/QnKGu/

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for that. I am using this version , is this correct? http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js

Comment: Yes, 1.7.1 will work just fine.  I would have to see more about your page to understand why it wouldn't be working.  The fiddle works for you though, correct?

Comment: Awesome, So quick and so nice. Works perfectly. Genius!!! .This helped in a very imp step of the application. I will be posting followup questions for the next steps and will share the link of the final application with you for your feedback.